# Encrypt 8 byte string / base64 encode / max length 20 bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, rncryptor

What is the best method/approach to encrypt and base64 encode a UTF String that has a max size of 20 bytes in objective-c? I'm leaning towards Blowfish because of the 8 byte block size.

Please provide some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to sacrifice some security for that. That's not enough space to squeeze in properly sized MAC and IV. Increasing the allowance to 32 characters would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

DES, 3DES and Blowfish have block sizes of 8-bytes so the encrypted output will be 8 bytes, Base64 encoding 8-bytes will result in 12 bytes.

AES has a block size of 16 so 8-bytes + padding will be 16-bytes of data. Base64 encoding 16-bytes will result in 24-bytes so AES will not work.

There are other issues such as CBC mode and an iv, a good scheme would use a random iv and transport it with the encrypted message. One could use the remaining bits in the Base64 to transmit a partial iv. But this is getting past the question.

AES is the current preferred symmetric encryption algorithm. DES is not longer recommended for new work and has some known weak keys. Blowfish is also not recommended but a lot of people like it and it may be better than DES.

Here is an example using 8-byte data with a 64-bit key and no iv. 3DES can be used by substitution of the Blowfish constants for 3DES and a 24-byte key. This is not a recommended solution, a good solution needs to consider usage, desired security, data value and potential attackers among other things such as iv and key.

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
               error:(NSError **)error
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmBlowfish,
                       0,
                       symmetricKey.bytes,
                       kCCKeySizeMinBlowfish,
                       nil,
                       dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes, dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError"
                                         code:ccStatus
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        dataOut = nil;
    }

    return dataOut;
}
```

Test:
I dropped the above method into a class names `Test`.

```
uint8_t keyBytes[] = {0x11,0x12,0x13,0x14,0x15,0x16,0x17,0x18};
NSData *key = [NSData dataWithBytes:keyBytes length:8];
uint8_t dateBytes[] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:dateBytes length:8];
NSLog(@"data:   %@", data);

NSError *error;
NSData *encryptData = [Test doCipher:data iv:nil key:key context:kCCEncrypt error:&error];
NSString *encryptString = [encryptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"encryptData:   %@", encryptData);
NSLog(@"encryptString: %@", encryptString);

NSData *decryptData = [Test doCipher:encryptData iv:nil key:key context:kCCDecrypt error:&error];
NSLog(@"decryptData:   %@", decryptData);
```

Output:

```
data:          01020304 05060708
encryptData:   9e8ec0a8 71ab9d10
encryptString: no7AqHGrnRA=
decryptData    01020304 05060708
```

Comment: Ok. Have you used the RNCryptor library on iOS? I'm trying to configure that library to use Blowfish 8-byte blocks but the output is always 27 bytes and not 8-bytes.

Comment: Just use Common Crypto. RNCryptor is a great library and includes real security features but you can't get that in 20-bytes.  See reference example added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example code.  Why doesn't the example code use an iv?

Comment: An iv adds security to the first block. This may or may not apply to your case. Security is much more than getting an edncryption method to work.

Comment: Like you mentioned. I could use the remaining 6-bytes for a random iv that gets base64 encoded and is appended to the encrypted messag. Right?

Comment: DES is a really bad idea, 56 bit keys are far too small. 3DES on the other hand has decent security (112 bits of security with a 168 bit key). When using Blowfish, use a key with at least 128 bits, not a 64 bit key.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, DES is a poor choice, I advised against it. 3DES is a reasonable solution, I should have added that to my answer, I will revise it.

Comment: @bickster Yes, you can pack 7 bytes of a random key into the 20-bytes of Base64 for passing to the decryption. Just make one of the iv bytes a constant.

Comment: @Zaph why do I have to make one of the bytes a constant?

Comment: I need to change a previous comment, I wrote: "can pack 7 bytes of a random **key**", I meant to write: "can pack 7 bytes of a random **iv**"

Comment: A 20-byte Base64 string can only contain 15 8-bit bytes, subtracting the 8 encrypted bytes that only leaves 7 bytes to contain the iv. The problem is the 8th iv byte and one way is to make it a constant, that still leaves 7 random iv bytes.

Comment: Got it.  One more question.  I changed your example code to use a 16-byte/128-bit key and the encrypted output size stayed the same.  Would that be a better approach then a 8-byte/64-bit key?

Comment: The key size is not related to the encrypted output size. The output size is a multiple of the block size. In general a 128-bit key is sufficient. But the real issue is how good is the key? How will it be shared between the two sides and how will it be protected, these are key management issues and are not easy to implement.