# PHP and Objective C Blowfish Encryption Encoding different

Tags: php, ios, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

The iOS and Android project I'm working on requires us to open a webview connecting to a 3rd party website. The problem is that the URL we call must be accompanied with some parameters encrypted using Blowfish with ECB mode.

This 3rd party uses PHP to encrypt/decrypt the parameters and they have given me the code they are using to do the encryption and decryption.

Based on that, in my iOS project, I'm using the FclBlowfish library (https://github.com/cantecim/FclBlowfish) to encrypt/decrypt the data.

After doing everything, the encryption/decryption was not working correctly, and the problem I just found out, after almost 5 hours working on this that in iOS the encryption is almost the same as PHP, but since blowfish generates weird characters, some of them were not being handled by iOS, making the decryption not work.

An example is:

In PHP, my encrypted string is
`p%FE& ¶4!É¢ßŸén™` but in iOS the same encrypted string is `p%FE&¶4!É¢ßén` as you can see, iOS is missing the **Ÿ** and **™**, making the final encrypted string different, so PHP cannot decrypt correctly.

The Code I'm using on iOS is:

```
FclBlowfish *bf = [[FclBlowfish alloc] init];
bf.Key = @"MyK3yF8n";
bf.IV = @"aaassss";
[bf prepare];

[bf encrypt:@"21988882121" withMode:modeEBC withPadding:paddingZero]
```

The encryption/decryption code this lib uses can be seen at: https://github.com/cantecim/FclBlowfish/blob/master/FclBlowfish.m

and the code in PHP is:

```
$initializationVectorSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'ecb');
$initializationVector = mcrypt_create_iv($initializationVectorSize, MCRYPT_RAND);

// Decrypt
$valor = $_GET['v'];
$valor = base64_decode($valor);

$valor = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'MyK3yF8n', $valor, 'ecb', $initializationVector);

print 'Valor: ' . $valor;

// Encrypt
$v = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'MyK3yF8n', $valor, 'ecb', $initializationVector);

print $v;
```

I would appreciate any help trying to figure out why iOS is missing some charecters, making the string non-decryptable in PHP.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So I opened the FclBlowfish code and saw that they were using the **NSISOLatin1StringEncoding** and **NSASCIIStringEncoding** Encoding in the Encryption and Decryption methods, then I decided to try a few others and found out that using **NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding** actually returns the correct encoding as the PHP one and decryption works like a charm!

Comment: 1. Using Blowfish is a poor idea, AES is the current encryption method--if you really care about security. 2. The combination of ECB and an iv does not make sense. 3 Verify that the padding is done the same way. 4. Using Apple supplied Common Crypto is probably a better choice, the encryption is in a standard library so it will not be subject to compiler issues and is trusted code.

Comment: @Zaph trust me when I say I would extinguish blowfish from ever being created. But the 3rd party website requires blowfish and I have to make work with it. :(

Comment: See this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28290622/451475) for an example Blowfish Common Crypto implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

After re-reading my post to see if I forgot any piece of information, it came to me that if the problem is the encoding, then the iOS library maybe using a NSEncoding different then it should be.

So I opened the FclBlowfish code and saw that they were using the **NSISOLatin1StringEncoding** and **NSASCIIStringEncoding** Encoding in the Encryption and Decryption methods, then I decided to try a few others and found out that using **NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding** actually returns the correct encoding as the PHP one and decryption works like a charm!

Hope this helps someone with the same problem!

Comment: You are better adding this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

IV must have ascii chars. So simply you can base64 encode it
For more info i wrote a comment on your issue : https://github.com/cantecim/FclBlowfish/issues/1#issuecomment-77517878

Comment: Why is there an iv with ecb mode?

Comment: It does not use iv with ecb mode, there is a check at first of any operation and after that it uses iv only in cbc mode